# PHP - is it safe to store anything in the $_SESSION superglobal?

Tags: php, security

Is it safe to store for example user permissions like

```
$_SESSION['username']='vputin';
$_SESSION['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['canlaunchnuclearstrike']=true;
```

Are there any security issues with this? Is it enough to check this on every page load and based on that either redirect to login page (and exit;) or continue?

Comment: Where do the permissions come from in the first place? A database?

Comment: Yes, they're loaded from a table that defines user types and permissions each user type has. Once there is a match for username+password, the row for that match contains user type and looks up permissions for that user type and loads them as a bunch of booleans in the $_SESSION var.

Comment: Are you literally an IT advisor for the DoD? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by "security". There is no abstract notion of "being secure". You can only be secure against specific threats. (This is called your "threat model".) If you don't say what you want to be secure against, it's impossible to say whether your solution is good or not. There's certainly no guarantee that zombies won't come and eat your site users when they log in to your site!

That said, session variables are inaccessible through the web server, so they form part of the opaque state of your web application which the user cannot see or exploit directly.

On the other hand, there are numerous avenues of attack that allow for leaking, stealing or abuse: If the session cookie is stolen, someone else can take over the session (and perhaps launch the nuke); this is an entirely common Starbucks-type scenario. Another vulnerability lies on the server itself: If the session data is stored in a file that is readable by other users, say on a shared host, then it is possible that others may obtain the session ID *and* the session data behind your back, by reading them directly from the server's disk.

It all depends! Probably best not to write your nuke strike management app in PHP on a shared host...

Comment: Understood :) I'm more worried that I may be doing something fundamentally wrong. If what I've described is the usual (and reasonably effective) way of securing access from unregistered users then it's good enough for me.

Comment: @DMIL: Sure. I suppose offering HTTP encryption would be a pretty important step if you have a serious application. Consider also that people may be reusing passwords, so if your site leaks login credentials, that may compromise entirely unrelated services (but the standard counter that this is the user's fault is fine).

Answer (score 1):

It is usually much better to store only the current user's ID in the session, and to look up permissions "live" from where they come from - e.g. a permissions database.

That way, you can be sure that changes in permissions reflect immediately upon what the user can and can't do.

Comment: Yes that would be more convenient as the user wouldn't have to login again but wouldn't that introduce an overhead - having to look up the permissions table on every page load?

Comment: @Darko hardly, if the table is properly indexed.

Comment: It's still more work for every request with **very** little benefit.

Comment: @symcbean I would call the ability to get changes in permissions straight away a pretty big benefit. Do you want Vladimir Putin to still be able to launch nukes when he retires? And on any average dynamic site, the amount of additional work is negligeable in light of what else needs to be pulled from the database on every request.

Comment: @Pekka - "get permissions straight away" - no, this requires an additional step compared with storing the data in the session, hence less immediate.

Comment: @symcbean this discussion makes no sense. In a system where the requirement is that changes in permissions are reflected immediately and not, say, after the user's next logon, there is simply no way around this "additional step". It's not a big deal either.

Comment: @Pekka: Where did this requirement come from?

Answer (score 0):

There could be session hijacking or other ways to read information from the session.
So an unencrypted password would be a security issue, but until the username is not a big deal you can save it in the session.

(Or use an user id and encode it to the username in your script)

So as a conclusion: only save "public" data, "nuklearmissile" etc should be resolved in the code an not rely on session data.

Answer (score 0):

Session data is saved on server. User just gets the session id into cookies, so server knows which user is it.

### Issues:

- Session id can be stolen, thou someone can fake the identity
- Session data on shared hostings can be shared among same users of one hosting server (on bad hosters ofc), so someone else can access your session data using same hosting server.

Session is pretty good way to store user identification, but it's not a good idea to store sensible information there.

Comment: If you need to store/retrieve sensitive information, where can you put it where these issues do not apply?

Comment: @symcbean Database is defenitely the best option.

Comment: how is this more secure than in the session? How does it prevent session hijack/fixation? How does it prevent other users on the same system accessing the data?

Comment: @symcbean It doesn't prevent from session hijack, but it does prevent other users on same system access your sensitive data, because session files sometimes on shared hostings are stored in same directory for all users of webserver. Database files are not stored in shared directory, tho database data isn't accessible for other users.

Comment: *sometimes* the session directory is shared, *sometimes* the database tables are not shared, *sometimes* shared servers don't use suPHP, *sometimes* shared servers use open_basedir to prevent scripts from one user reading data (such as database credentials) stored in scripts belonging to different users, *sometimes* the session is stored in the database.